# Linux replace newline

Tags: linux, awk, sed

Input

```
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
```

Output

```
aaaa
< _jupijuice_ >
bbbb
< _jupijuice_ >
cccc
< _jupijuice_ >
```

In simple words, replace \n with \n< *jupijuice* >\n

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In regular expressions you can use `$` to match end of line:

```
sed 's/$/\n< _jupijuice_ >/' input.txt
```

Comment: no need of the cat, just give the file name to sed directly ;-). `\n` in other sed than GNU will failed if in replacment pattern, you need a real new line in this case.

Answer (score 5):

```
awk '{print; print "< _jupijuice_ >"}' input.txt
```

Output:

```
aaaa
< _jupijuice_ >
bbbb
< _jupijuice_ >
cccc
< _jupijuice_ >
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sed 'a\
< _jupijuice_ >' YourFile
```

append a line `<...>` after each line

Comment: what is best is  best → http://sourceforge.net/projects/anytextfile/ this is my program, needed this small sed command for dividing blocks, for books reading, tweets reading like from https://github.com/sferik/t etc.

Comment: sorry, don't have access to your project code. Using a sed into another package is maybe not the best. I don't know lazarus code but ther is no code allowing text modfication as internal code ? Any instruction using regex manipulation will certainly suite your need

Answer (score 2):

This should do:

```
awk '$0=$0"\n< _jupijuice_ >"'
```